# Mathjax issue with MathJax.Hub.Queue and Typeset

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Following [this page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.5-latest/typeset.html), I try to display a simple equation into a div container.

Here is an example on [this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/v4zhLgmL/42/)

It seems that equation is not interpreted as a Mathjax equation and I don't know how to make it rendered.

**JS :**

```
MathJax.Hub.Config(
{
    messageStyle: "none",
    TeX: 
    { 
        equationNumbers: 
        {
            autoNumber: "all"
        } 
    },
    tex2jax: 
    {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']], 
        displayMath: [ ['\\begin{displaymath}','\\end{displaymath}'], ['\\begin{equation}','\\end{equation}'] ],
        processEscapes: true,
        preview: "none"
    }
});

document.getElementById("containerCanvas").innerHTML = "$ax+b=c$";
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"containerCanvas"]);
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle loads the AsciiMath input jax, not the TeX input jax, so dollar not TeX-delimiter math will be processed.  Try using `config=TeX-AMS_CHTML` instead of `config=AM_CHTML`.

Comment: thanks, that dit it !

Comment: I've made that an answer, so that you can accept it.  That way your question will be marked as having an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsFiddle loads the AsciiMath input jax, not the TeX input jax, so dollar not TeX-delimiter math will be processed. Try using `config=TeX-AMS_CHTML` instead of `config=AM_CHTML`.